# flyway cli failing to connect to mysql database - getDatabaseTypeForUrl

Tags: flyway

I've been trying without success to connect to a local mySQL database, it keeps failing with the errors listed below.

```
[root@stargate drivers]# flyway info -X -url='"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sms_database"'
DEBUG: Loading config file: /home/development/wip/flyway-9.1.3/conf/flyway.conf
DEBUG: Loading config file: /root/flyway.conf
DEBUG: Unable to load config file: /home/development/wip/flyway-9.1.3/drivers/flyway.conf
DEBUG: Using configuration:
DEBUG: flyway.jarDirs -> /home/development/wip/flyway-9.1.3/jars
DEBUG: flyway.locations -> service-sms/service-sms
DEBUG: flyway.password -> ********
DEBUG: flyway.url -> "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sms_database"
DEBUG: flyway.user -> root
ERROR: Unexpected error
org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: No database found to handle "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sms_database"
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.DatabaseTypeRegister.getDatabaseTypeForUrl(DatabaseTypeRegister.java:54)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.DriverDataSource.<init>(DriverDataSource.java:109)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.DriverDataSource.<init>(DriverDataSource.java:89)
        at org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.ClassicConfiguration.configure(ClassicConfiguration.java:1528)
        at org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.FluentConfiguration.configuration(FluentConfiguration.java:943)
        at org.flywaydb.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:157)
```

I've confirmed connectivity:

```
[root@stargate drivers]# mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -ppassword
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 26
Server version: 8.0.23-vitess 

Copyright (c) 2000, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> status;
--------------
mysql  Ver 8.0.26 for Linux on x86_64 (Source distribution)

Connection id:          26
Current database:
Current user:           vt_app@localhost
SSL:                    Not in use
Current pager:          stdout
Using outfile:          ''
Using delimiter:        ;
Server version:         8.0.23-vitess 
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
Server characterset:    utf8mb4
Db     characterset:    utf8mb4
Client characterset:    utf8mb4
Conn.  characterset:    utf8mb4
TCP port:               3306
Binary data as:         Hexadecimal
--------------
```

I've tried both the mariadb-java-client-2.7.3.jar and mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar drivers and error is the same. Any advice ?

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed by removing the extra '' characters from the URL string.